# div rotation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to rotate the `div class="cover"` *180 degree whts* problem help me.

Here are my files:

---

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tweet">
    <button type="submit"><span class="icon-twitter"><img src="2.jpg"></img></span>Tweet</button>
    <div class="count">10.5K</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <span class="icon-twitter"><img src="2.jpg"></img></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="jas.js"></script>
```

---

**CSS code:**

```
.cover {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 200px;
    height:70px;
    background:linear-gradient(#30CCFC, #2CC5EF);
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #54AED0;
    cursor:pointer;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transform-origin: center bottom; 
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
}

.open {
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),inset 0 0 1px 1px #54AED0;
    background: linear-gradient(#33CEFE, #38D6FD);
}
```

---

**JavaScript code:**

```
$('.cover').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Try this " transform: rotate(-180deg); " .

Comment: you say: "div rotation not working correctly". How should it work?  `-ms-transform` is only for IE, whithout prefix works fine

Answer (score 0):

Use following css

```
.cover {
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);

    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);

    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);

    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        /*visibility:hidden;*/

}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hmu3eLj0/1/)

> For more info [**Read**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/)

Comment: where use this css

Comment: @Asad : offcourse in your .cover class .., see my demo

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[working pen](http://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/mExvmy)

```
.open {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```